# Why dose preceding list assignment cause break statement not to execute?

Tags: python, list

I have come across a strange behavior using the python break statement within a try-except block.

```
i=0
lst=[]
while i < 5:
    try:  
        if i < 3:
            raise Exception('spam', 'eggs')
        #lst[0]=i
        print('-'+str(i)+'-')
        break
    except:
        i=i+1
        print(str(i)+' ',end='')
```

> 1 2 3 -3-

But if I remove the commented line:

```
i=0
lst=[]
while i < 5:
    try:  
        if i < 3:
            raise Exception('spam', 'eggs')
        lst[0]=i
        print('-'+str(i)+'-')
        break
    except:
        i=i+1
        print(str(i)+' ',end='')
```

> 1 2 3 4 5

Why has the list assignment caused the break to no longer happen? Can someone explain what is going on here.

Comment: Because it raises an exception.

Comment: That except block catches _all_ errors including `IndexError`.

Comment: **Don't use bare except clauses**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lst` is an empty list. Attempting to access elements that do not exist, such as `lst[0]` will raise an `IndexError` exception. That exception is then caught in the exception handler, corrupting your expected results.

First of all, you generally should not use bare exception handlers; restrict your exception handler to those exceptions that it knows how to handle. Unrestricted exception handlers make it possible for unexpected exceptions to be hidden, as is the case here.

If you want to store the index in `lst` either make sure that your list is long enough, or use `append()` or `insert()` to add it to the end or at the beginning of the list.

Using `Exception` to create your own exceptions is often not the best thing to do either because it makes it difficult to distinguish your exception from others:

```
for i in range(2):
    try:
        if i == 0:
            raise Exception('spam', 'eggs')
        else:
            1/0    # cause ZeroDivisionError
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))
```

Running that code outputs:

```
Exception('spam', 'eggs')
ZeroDivisionError('division by zero',)
```

Because `ZeroDivisionError` is a subclass of `Exception` it is also caught by the handler. To solve this you can create your own `Exception` subclass:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass
```

Now you can easily check for the exception that you know how to handle:

```
for i in range(2):
    try:
        if i == 0:
            raise MyException('spam', 'eggs')
        else:
            1/0    # cause ZeroDivisionError
    except MyException as e:
        print(repr(e))
```

Running this code:

```
MyException('spam', 'eggs')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 6, in 
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

shows that your custom exception is caught and handled, but unexpected exceptions are not. If you want to handle the unexpected ones too then add a second exception handler *after* the first:

```
    except MyException as e:
        print(repr(e))
    except Exception as e:
        print('Unexpected exception', e)
        raise
```

Answer (score 1):

If you treat the exception:

```
i=0
lst=[]
while i < 5:
    try:
        if i < 3:
            raise Exception('spam', 'eggs')
        lst[0]=i
        print('-'+str(i)+'-')
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        i=i+1
        print(str(i))
```

You will realize that you get an [IndexError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.IndexError):

```
list assignment index out of range
```

since your list is empty, you can not access/assign at that index. If you want to insert items to the list use `append`:

```
lst.append(i)
```

or `insert`:

```
lst.insert(0, i)
```

depending on what you want to do. Read more [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).